# Which char is not in UTF-16?

Tags: c#, char, utf-16

I need some chars that UTF-16 doesn´t support. I can´t find them.
Can you please help me?

```
char[] letters = tbvstup.Text.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
{
    if(letters[i] == 'ě' || letters[i] == 'č' || letters[i] == 'ř' || letters[i] == 'ť' || letters[i] == 'ď' || letters[i] == 'ň' || letters[i] == 'ů')
    {
        ASCII = false;
        pbascii.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    if (letters[i] == '˛' || letters[i] == '˘' || letters[i] == 'ˇ' || letters[i] == '˙' || letters[i] == '€' || letters[i] == '‡' || letters[i] == '‰' || letters[i] == 'ě' || letters[i] == 'č' || letters[i] == 'ř' || letters[i] == 'ť' || letters[i] == 'ď' || letters[i] == 'ň' || letters[i] == 'ů')
    {
        ISO = false;
        pbiso.BackColor = Color.Red;   
    }
    if (letters[i] == '€')
    {
        CP852 = false;
        pbcp852.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    if (letters[i] == '£')
    {
        CP1250 = false;
        pbcp1250.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    if (letters[i] == '') // <-- What do I need to put here?
    {
        UTF16 = false;
        pbutf16.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) is a variable-length encoding which support *all* of Unicode.

Comment: Oh and please edit your question to tell us what language you're using.

Comment: Do you actually mean [UCS-2](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-ucs-2-character-encoding)?

Comment: What do you mean by "not supported by UTF-16"? Maybe something like  that requires two 16-bit "characters"?

Comment: Right. Replace `if (letters[i] == '') // <-- What do I need to put here?` with `if (false) // UTF-16 supports the whole Unicode character set`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ASCII** is a 7-bit encoding where there is a 1:1 relationship between character code and byte that is stored.

**CP852**, **CP1250** and others used the extra bit (compared to ASCII) so they have 128 extra values to encode extra characters. They may redefine some of the lower 128 values. There still is a 1:1 relationship between character and byte stored, as in: if it doesn't fit into a byte, it cannot be in this codepage (that is why there are so many codepages).

**UTF-8** and **UTF-16** are very different. They belong to the Unicode character set that assigns *unique* numbers to any character from any language (present or ancient - even hieroglyphics have their own [set of values](https://unidecoder.azurewebsites.net/block/Egyptian%20Hieroglyphs)). The unicode values (codepoints) do not limit themselves to what would fit in some number of bits, as that is the job of the encoding: UTF-8 uses 8-bit units (also known as bytes) and (for english) mainly uses one byte per character, but may use up to six as needed. UTF-16 uses 16-bit units and may need two of them to encode a specific codepoint.

So there is no valid character (as defined by unicode) that cannot be encoded in UTF-16, although the higher valued characters may need two 16-bit units ("surrogate pair").

C# (.Net, really) uses a 16-bit `char` datatype, so in effect uses UTF-16 internally.

See for more info: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Unlike VB4 and Win32, which were indeed originally designed for UCS-2, .NET from the start uses UTF-16, which is why the specification and documentation say so.